# Download file with Selenium when by clicking link it will load up different page from which the download will start

Tags: python, selenium

I have the pipeline working, but facing issues with redirected links

URL for testing:
https://www.foundationforintermediaries.co.uk/document-library/

- Try to download **Buy To Let Individual Product Guide**

How to download the file by using Selenium which has redirected link?

The problem which I receiving:
[image]

I'm using:

```
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs',{
        'credentials_enable_service': False,
        'profile': {
            'password_manager_enabled': False, 
        },
        'download': {
            'default_directory': "PATH"
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If your machine is Windows-based, try to use [AUTOIT](https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html)

Comment: This is a really bad way of doing this, I know about the way around, but unfortunately, they are dirty, I thought Selenium can do this.

But thank you for suggestion